# Why a variable and explicit memory address have different values?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm facing a strange behaviour, on Visual Studio 2013. I have a variable `CZipArchive zip` and for some reason its behaviour is wrong on my project.

When I get its address (`&zip` -> `0x0018fae0`) and make an explicit memory reference, the values are right. See this image bellow:

[Visual Studio 2013 - Watch 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPhlA.png)

When I check the addres of member `&zip.m_bCaseSensitive`, the address is `0x0018fb00`, but if I check the address of the same property, using the explicit addres instead of variable zip `(*(CZipArchive*)(0x0018fae0)).m_bCaseSensitive`, the address is `0x0018faf0`.

The correct value is the one using the explicit memory address and using the zip variable, the value is wrong.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: &zip -> 0x0018fae0, It's not a `8` I guess in your screenshot right ?

Comment: @Hacketo, right. Fixed, Thanks.

Comment: How can anyone answer without seeing your code?

Comment: @Drmmr, what code should I post? My Project got 400+ sources files